# Load pdf from external url via php

Tags: php, security

I am trying to allow a user to download a pdf of sensitive information from an API. However, the URL returned by the API is not secure as details could potentially be guessed to obtain somebody else's information. My intention is to authenticate the user and, if they pass, pass the file directly to them. At the moment, I'm using the following, however, it doesn't work as the `filesize()` function apparently doesn't work with an http link.

```
$filename = "http://api.com/person/1234/document/1234/data?key=1234&hash=1234";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: You need file_get_contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<?php echo file_get_contents("http://api.com/person/1234/document/1234/data?key=1234&hash=1234");`

Comment: Spits out a load of garbage, but better than I'm getting at the moment. Do I need to add file headers?

Comment: Yes... sorry. Add `header("Content-type:application/pdf");`

Comment: Just figured that out. Cheers! It's always simpler than you think…